# How to delete all lines that contain a number lower than given value from a text file?

Tags: python, python-re

I'm trying to remove every line from a file that has any number below the value of -2000. I'm quite new to python and it's most likely that I don't understand the `re` module, nor am I sure about the method I am using.

Here is the sample file:

```
{ "Position": { "X": -1660.313, "Y": -3107.795, "Z": 12.85458 }
{ "Position": { "X": -494.0083, "Y": 57.33647, "Z": 56.59263 }
{ "Position": { "X": -1039.662, "Y": -2641.444, "Z": 36.96656 }
```

And here is what I've got:

```
 with open('file.json','r') as input:
    with open("temp.json", 'w') as output:  
        for line in input:
            match = re.search(r'('-'\d+)', line)
            my_number = float(match.group())
            if my_number < -2000:
                output.write(line.strip())
```

As for now I'm sure that in `re.search(r'('-'\d+))`, `'-'`is wrong. I'm also not sure about the proper use of `match.group()`.

If anyone would guide me in the right direction or suggest a different method I would be grateful.

Comment: Aren't you getting an error for `r'('-'\d+)'`

Comment: `re.search(r'-\d')` is what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what I should do with match.group() ? It also gives me an error this time "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'".

Comment: do you want to match `-2000` number by itself, or maybe ignore that? obviously something like `-2000.01` should be included, since its less than  the desired value.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a JSON file? The lines are not valid JSON.

Comment: You don't need a capture group.

Comment: It's just a sample from the file that can be treated as a regular txt. The number does not need to be included.

Comment: The lines would be valid JSON if they had a second `}` at the end. Is that that how it actually is?

Comment: Yes, it is like that. The lines were just too long to copy whole and I forgot about that.

Comment: Putting multiple JSONs in a file like this is bad design. The file should be a single JSON list. To add to it, you load the file, append to the list, then dump that back to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like `r'-[2-9]\d{3,}'` that should match -2000 or lower.

> **Explanation**: match `-` for negative and a number between `2-9`, followed by any `3` or more digits.

Why use regex? It's actually faster than an approach with `json.loads` (see below).

The downside, however is it seems to also match -2000 by itself.

```
import re

# please note: not valid JSON here
line = '{ "Position": { "X": -1660.313, "Y": -3107.795, "Z": 12.85458 }'

match = re.search(r'-[2-9]\d{3,}', line)

print(bool(match))
print(match.group(0))
```

Output:

```
True
-3107
```

---

To include lines with numbers that are exactly `-2000` (which is an edge case) you can use `re.findall` to find all numbers that are `-2000` or below, then cast the numeric values to `float`, and do a comparison similar to how you had it above:

```py
import re


NEG_TARGET_RE = re.compile(r'-[2-9]\d{3,}(?:\.\d+)?')


def has_any_num_less_than_target(line, target=-2000) -> bool:
    for m in NEG_TARGET_RE.findall(line):
        if float(m) < target:
            return True

    return False


line = '{ "Position": { "X": -1660.313, "Y": -2000.795, "Z": 12.85458 }'
print(has_any_num_less_than_target(line))  # True

line = '{ "Position": { "X": -1660.313, "Y": -2000, "Z": -2000.000 }'
print(has_any_num_less_than_target(line))  # False
```

#### Performance Comparison

Quick benchmarks show that regex approach is ~4x faster than an approach with `json.loads`.

```py
import json
from timeit import timeit

lines = """
{ "Position": { "X": -1660.313, "Y": -3107.795, "Z": 12.85458 } }
{ "Position": { "X": -494.0083, "Y": 57.33647, "Z": 56.59263 } }
{ "Position": { "X": -1039.662, "Y": -2641.444, "Z": 36.96656 } }
"""

print('json:  ', timeit(r"""
for line in lines.strip().split('\n'):
    d = json.loads(line)
    if all(x >= -2000 for x in d['Position'].values()):
        ...
""", globals=globals(), number=1000))

print('re:    ', timeit(r"""
for line in lines.strip().split('\n'):
    if not has_any_num_less_than_target(line):
        ...
""", globals=globals(), number=1000))
```

Result:

```
json:   0.004367416957393289
re:     0.0011514590587466955
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a regular expression. Parse the line as JSON and test that.

```
with open('file.json','r') as input, open("temp.json", 'w') as output:  
    for line in input:
        d = json.loads(line)
        if all(x >= -2000 for x in d['Position'].values()):
            output.write(line)
```

Also, don't write `line.strip()`. This will remove the newlines, so the output file will have everything on one long line, instead of a separate line for each item like the input file.

This answer assumes that you made a mistake when copying the lines into your question. To be valid JSON the lines would have to be like:

```
{ "Position": { "X": -1660.313, "Y": -3107.795, "Z": 12.85458 } }
```

with a second `}` at the end.

Comment: I thought of that, but each line is not a valid json though - at least based on above. It looks like end `}` is missing to make it as valid.

Comment: I noticed that, and mentioned it in a comment above. I'm hoping this is a copying error in the question.